# How to use delay with HTTPClient Rxjs 6.3.0

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient, rxjs6

Usind delay with HTTPClient object gives me error as below:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Number' has no compatible call signatures.

TS:

```
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.http.get(url,{params:search})
          .pipe(
              delay(1000),
              map(res => res)
          , catchError((error: any) => {
              return Observable.throw(error)
        }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't delay the HTTP response, but you can delay the return value. Here is the correct code

```
this.http.get(url,{params:search})
          .pipe(
              map(res => res),
              delay(1000), 
              catchError((error: any) => {
                 return Observable.throw(error)
              }
           ));
```

Comment: Are you gettign the HTTP Response?

Comment: Its compile time error. Also, my idea was to delay the request, but as u suggested delay after response doesn't serve that purpose.

Comment: you can't delay the HTTP Request. Its simple one. Use res:any

Comment: Doesn't work. Might be something related to tsconfig